# Error to convert String to Byte[ ] with MonoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, converters

```
alert2.Clicked += (object sender2, UIButtonEventArgs e2) => {

    if(e2.ButtonIndex == 0){

        string vai = alert2.GetTextField (0).Text;
        Console.WriteLine(vai);

        byte[] bit = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(vai);
        Console.WriteLine(bit);
        //bit = Convert.ToBase64String({vai});

        foreach (var charac in characteristic.Service.Characteristics) {
                    characteristic.Service.Peripheral.WriteValue (NSData.FromArray (bit), charac, CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse);
                }

        }

};
```

I'm taking the text from UIAlertView, when I use ""Console.WriteLine(vai); return to me the right value, like 002, 001, 1, 2 or anything else.
But when I convert the string to byte,  "byte[] bit = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(vai);", in the output returns "System.Byte[]"

and not the value...My app doesn't work!

Comment: If you console.writeline a byte array, it just calls ToString() on the byte array, hence the output, what exactly are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Ok, but my problem isn't the console...
I'm sending the bytes via Bluetooth LE and the device execute a command... Like Arduino..
But the device don't receive the bytes!
Before it I was doing it automatically, I started the app with a value in "bit", this works, but to get the valor from TextView don't

Comment: If you are debugging and want to see what's in the byte array, then set a breakpoint and inspect it in the debugger, outputting the contents to the console is not a useful debugging too for this scenario.